# perl split string on a single char, not on repeated char

Tags: perl, split, char

I am using an existing perl script to process a text file output from a database query which I have no control over.

The data contains fields separated by '|', but some fields contain '||'. There are no empty fields. There may be spaces on either side of the field separator which I would also like to remove.

I cannot find a simple way to achieve this, apart from changing the '||' to something else, and putting it hack after the split, which seems a bit heavy going.

The file is substantial (typically up to about 100M).

Using `split(/ *\| */, $line)` works apart from the '||' character.

Any thought please?

Answer (score 3):

```
split /\s*(?<!\|)\|(?!\|)\s*/
```

Comment: Simple when some one shows me how. Works well, and is faster than my remove and replace (not surprisingly).

Answer (score 3):

you can use negative look-behind and look-ahead to ensure there are no `|` symbols around the `|` you're splitting on:

```
split / \s* (?<!\|) \| (?!\|) \s* /x
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at using [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV/lib/Text/CSV.pm) or [Tie::Handle::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~danboo/Tie-Handle-CSV/lib/Tie/Handle/CSV.pm) to run through the file. If the text file has been done properly fields that contain *||* will be quoted.

Comment: I think my problem started because there isn't input data protection on the user input. I guess next thing is some one using a single pipe, then I'll have to have a rethink! Thanks for your time